# get answer sequence of numbers in Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

how to  add sequence numbers to each item in a list?

(`['a', 'b', 7]) ---> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 7)]`

I can not get exactly answer...

Comment: `enumerate()` ?

Comment: `list(enumerate(['a', 'b', 7])`

Answer (score 1):

enumerate will numerate iterable list , by default it starts from 0

If 1 is desired pass start=1

```
f = (['a', 'b', 7])

list(enumerate(f, start=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the enumerate object. Enumerate will pair each item in a collection with its index in that collection. For example:

```
enumerate(['a', 'b', 7])
```

will return an enumerate object that when casted to a list like this:

```
list(enumerate(['a', 'b', 7]))
```

will return the list

```
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is using a [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function:

```
>>> f = ['a', 'b', 7]
>>> list(zip(range(1, len(f)+1), f))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 7)]
```